# "Eager macro-expansion failure" message when starting Emacs 28.2 from the mac terminal

Tags: error, mac

I have upgraded my emacs using `brew install emacs-plus`. Now when I run `emacs &` from the terminal, the following message appears.

> Eager macro-expansion failure: (wrong-number-of-arguments (3 . 4) 2)
> Eager macro-expansion failure: (wrong-number-of-arguments (3 . 4) 2)
> Error loading autoloads: (wrong-number-of-arguments (3 . 4) 2)

This message didn't used to appear before the upgrade. I'd like to resolve whatever the problem is, so that no message will appear upon startup.

As per the suggestions given in [this post](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/54455/how-to-get-a-stack-trace-for-eager-macro-expansion-failure) (specifically, in [this comment](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/54455/how-to-get-a-stack-trace-for-eager-macro-expansion-failure#comment85090_54455)), I have eliminated the init file altogether, but this didn't change the situation in any way.

**My computer**: iMac, late 2013
**My OS**: macOS Catalina, version 10.15.7
**My Emacs version**: 28.2 (9.0)

Comment: I have no solution for you, but that kind of error suggests that there are some out of date compiled emacs lisp files being used (`.elc`).  `emacs -Q --debug-init` may be enough to pinpoint the culprit. It is surprising that this would happen with `emacs -Q`, though, since `-Q` should cause Emacs to load just the bare essentials, and brew should package Emacs up with the correct stuff. If I were you I would start fresh. Uninstall everything related to Emacs you have, unset any Emacs related environment variables (`EMACSLOADPATH`), move your .emacs.d directory aside, then re-install.

Comment: Another thing to look at: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/74302/starting-emacs-with-q-lists-the-packages-from-my-init-file. Just because you start with `emacs -Q` doesn't prevent Emacs from looking at some things in your `.emacs.d`, though arguably for a byte compiled elisp problem it should handle what happened to your more gracefully. See also the comment on that post: If you want a completely clean emacs startup, then you need to do `HOME=/tmp emacs -Q` -- but I would suggest some directory other than `/tmp` -- make a new temp dir that is empty instead.

Comment: @MattArmstrong I never said that this happened with `emacs -Q`. It doesn't.

I uninstalled the previous version of emacs before installing the new one with Homebrew.

What should I look for when running `emacs -Q --debug-init?`

Comment: @MattArmstrong In my system there is no files named ~/.emacs, ~/.emacs.el, ~/.emacs.d/init.el, or ~/.config/emacs/init.el, and the entire computer doesn't contain any files named default.el or site-start.el.

Comment: @MattArmstrong With `HOME=/tmp emacs` the error message doesn't occur.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message was resolved once the package list was updated.